# Microservices - using strict types to enforce the API?

Tags: json, haskell, service, types, microservices

I am writing two separate services. The output of the first service feeds into the second. Should I use a shared library so the type checker can make sure the interfaces match?

The "products" service takes an `Application` and produces `Products`.

The "scores" service takes `Application` and `Products` and produces a `Score`. It uses less than half of the information available.

Should I have the interface for "scores" exactly match the output of "products", even though it doesn't use all the information? Both will be used by the same client, and it would be convenient for it not to have to do any transformation. I can use a shared library containing only types and json serialization code that can enforce this. The build system can depend on old versions of the shared lib, so as long as I keep it forward compatible, I shouldn't need to update "scores" when fields are added to the output of "products".

Or should I have "scores" reinvent its own concept of the interface, with only the fields it needs? The field names might not match, making it more difficult for the client to connect them. The advantage is the interfaces are completely de-coupled.

Comment: I would use the same interface for both initially, separating them sounds a bit like premature optimization (at least from the information you gave). Also I think reworking the interface later on should not be a big problem due to haskells type safety, if you do have the need to separate them later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanna follow the microservices way then I'd say don't use the shared library.

The whole point of this concept is decoupling the services. If you make a shared library which contains some classes which are "the same" for multiple services then each time when a service want to enhance these classes, it has to be done within the shared library, forcing the other services to adapt.

Decoupling the services makes possible for each of them to evolve individually.

Comment: Situation OP laid out is not two services providing the same or a similar API, but one service being the input of another and using the same datatypes for the service and client. That doesn't seem unreasonable at all to me.